# Validar que fecha y hora no sean menor a la actual en input datetime-local

Tags: php, html5

Tengo un campo de tipo datetime-local en un formulario, y necesito que la fecha y hora ingresada no sean menores a las actuales. ¿Es posible hacer eso? probé con el atributo min de html5 y le asigne la fecha y hora actuales para evitar que fueran ingresadas sin obtener un buen resultado. El campo en la base de datos es de  un datetime. No es si es posible hacerlo usando javascript ¿algún ejemplo?

```
<div class="form-group">

 <label>Hrs y Fecha de Inicio</label>
 <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="fecha_ini" name="fecha_ini" min="<?php localtime();?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Estas usando datetimepicker? o un input type = "date"??

Comment: estoy usando un input type="datetime-local" no se que tanta diferencia exista al usar un  datetimepicker(no se lo que es, siempre uso inputs de tipo  date)

Comment: [este es un datetimepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) y lo que quieres se puede hacer de muchas maneras

Comment: Igual me serviría de ejemplo si sabes  como usando datetimepicker lo  podría implementar de ser necesario.

Answer (score 2):

Para hacerlo con PHP

```
$hoy             = date("Y-m-d");
$fechaFormulario = "2017-10-01";

// Si la fecha es de apartir de hoy => true 
if ($hoy <= $fechaFormulario) {

    echo "Fecha a partir de hoy";
}
else {

    echo "Debes selecionar una fecha mayor a Hoy";
}
```

Para hacerlo con javascript:(No muy recomendable)

```js
var hoy             = new Date();
var fechaFormulario = new Date('2017-10-1');

// Comparamos solo las fechas => no las horas!!
hoy.setHours(0,0,0,0);  // Lo iniciamos a 00:00 horas

if (hoy <= fechaFormulario) {

  console.log("Fecha a partir de hoy");
}
else {
  console.log("Debes elegir una fecha mayor que hoy");
}
```

Validando un datetimepicker:(Si te fijas en este no le das opciones al usuario para elegir fechas anteriores al dia de hoy)

```js
var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    minDate: dateToday,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="from">From</label> <input type="text" id="from" name="from"/> <label for="to">to</label> <input type="text" id="to" name="to"/>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

Sí es posible añadir el atributo `min` haciendo uso de `PHP` , ¿ Su error? la función [locatime()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.localtime.php) retorna un `array`. Además el formato de la fecha debe ser `RFC 3339`.

Entonces podríamos recurrir a la función [date()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) pasando el formato respectivo :

```
<div class="form-group">

 <label>Hrs y Fecha de Inicio</label>
 <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="fecha_ini" 
        name="fecha_ini" min="<?php echo  date('Y-m-d\TH:i'); ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Eso funciona de manera genial, aunque aun así me permite ingresar una hora anterior, se agradece la respuesta

Comment: @CristianOx21 es posible porque esto dependerá de la configuración de su servidor. Saludos